Fail2ban regex identifies bad IP addresses but doesn't ban them in one jail, but does in others
I run an Ubuntu server 24.04 LTS with Fail2ban v 1.1.0.1 installed.
I had difficulty with an earlier version of Fail2ban after upgrading to 24.04 LTS, which were resolved (see https://www.airix.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=89:ubuntu-2404-with-fail2ban-issue-fix&catid=53:featured&Itemid=271).
I now have a strange situation whereby Fail2ban correctly identifies and bans bad IP addresses via the postfix jail...BUT, although it identifies bad IP addresses via the dovecot jail, it does not ban them.
Thus, running this command:
fail2ban-regex /var/log/mail.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/dovecot.conf[mode=aggressive]

...results in over 3,000 matches, but none of the related IP addresses are banned.
The entries in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local are:
[dovecot]
enabled  = true
mode     = aggressive
filter   = dovecot
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log
protocol = all
maxretry = 2
[postfix]
enabled  = true
mode     = aggressive
maxretry = 2
protocol = all
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log

